# Things to consider before modifying a primary key

Tags: oracle, primary-key

I have a need where the current PK can have a duplicate value so we are deciding to change it to a composite key to allow for the duplicate. We will be adding another column to the PK. I would like some tips on what things to take into consideration before changing it?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that jumps to my mind is are there any foreign keys that reference that primary key that is going to be changed, if there are then you need to alter the foreign keys too which can mean adding additional columns to the child table to accomplish this.

Second thing, all PK-s in Oracle are supported by a unique index, this is also used for quick access to a specific row if the select queries on that table are hitting that index, if you change the PK you change the index so select queries that previously used the old index might not use the newly created one and can be slower because of that.

Third thing, adding an additional column to make the new composite PK you are implicitly putting a not null constraint on that additional column, this means there should be no null values in it before creating the new PK and no null values in it after.